# matplotlib: add circle to plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I add a small filled circle or point to a countour plot in matplotlib?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is an example, using [pylab.Circle](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Circle):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

e = np.e
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 5, 100), np.linspace(0, 5, 100))
F = X ** Y
G = Y ** X

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
circ = plt.Circle((e, e), radius=0.07, color='g')
plt.contour(X, Y, (F - G), [0])
ax.add_patch(circ)
plt.show()
```

[image]

And [here is another example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/patch_collection.html) (though not a contour plot) from the docs.

Or, you could just use `plot`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

e = np.e
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 5, 100), np.linspace(0, 5, 100))
F = X ** Y
G = Y ** X

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.contour(X, Y, (F - G), [0])
plt.plot([e], [e], 'g.', markersize=20.0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Let's take it line-by-line. What's the first line that doesn't make sense?

Comment: `F = X ** Y
G = Y ** X
`

This is the one

Comment: `X` and `Y` are NumPy arrays of shape `(100, 100)`. `**` is the exponentiation operator. Arithmetic operations on NumPy arrays are performed element-wise. So `X ** Y` is the exponentiation of `X` to the `Y`th power, done for each element in `X` with the corresponding element in `Y`. Try it out in a Python interpreter, perhaps with smaller arrays for `X` and `Y` so the result is easier to see.

Comment: The plot is showing the roots of the equation `x^y = y^x`. These is the obvious solution, the straight line `x = y`. But then there is also that curved line, shown above.