# python scatter plot can a plot point have multiple colors

Tags: python, colors, scatter-plot

I am plotting a scatterplot on a tkinter canvas and have a basic call such as the following which works great

```
ax.scatter(_x, _y, _z, marker=_m, c=_c ,s=_s, picker=True, alpha=1)
```

My questions is, is it possible for a plot point to have two colors, ie instead of a red circle, have a half red/half green circle.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Matplotlib half black and half white circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326069/matplotlib-half-black-and-half-white-circle)

I found the same question here. It is a hard one to find as search words are not common