# Python: how to add curves in an image

Tags: python

I have an image as follows:

[image]

The image is generated in Python. I want to further plot a curve on top of the image, which encloses the white region. I have already got the pixel indices for the region border. I know in Matlab, e.g., it can be simply done by :

```
hold on
plot(x,y,'r-') %x and y are the indices of boundary pixels.
```

The resultant image should be like this:

[image]

How can I do that contour on top of the image in Python, not by cv2.drawContours? Anyone can help me with the problem?

Comment: Matplotlib is almost the same syntax as Matlab

Comment: @cricket_007: but how to 'hold on' when plotting curves on top of the image?

Comment: I got it. Just add plt.show() in the end of plotting codes

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Pillow library for it. Without going into the whole solution, there's a good example in their tutorial on how to read an image an do some postscript drawing on top of it: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/handbook/tutorial.html#drawing-postscript

You pretty much only need to change the rectangle to a circle instead.

The cut down example is:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import PSDraw

im = Image.open("lena.ppm")
box = (1*72, 2*72, 7*72, 10*72) # in points

ps = PSDraw.PSDraw() # default is sys.stdout
ps.begin_document(title)

# draw the image (75 dpi)
ps.image(box, im, 75)
ps.rectangle(box)

ps.end_document()
```

PS. I'm assuming that by "I have an image as follows:" you mean, you have an image file and want to process that, not that you're generating that graph in python already. If you're using something like `matplotlib` to generate it in the first place, you can add it there instead.

If you're already doing it in `matplotlib`, then the question is likely a duplicate of [matplotlib: add circle to plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439639/matplotlib-add-circle-to-plot)

Comment: Thank for your reply! The image display is generated by matplot.pyplot.imshow. What I want to do is to just add a boundary curve, right following the imshow command, similarly to using 'hold on' in Matlab. I will try your codes.